# Better Grid for VB6 that supports row and column spanning?

Tags: datagrid, vb6, activex

Can anyone suggest me better **grid** for **vb 6** which have **row-span**, **column-span** facility and can work with around **150000 rows.**
So we can achieve following kind of solution.  [image: Sample grid display]

Comment: Old (?) True DB Grid. I haven't worked with spans, but it has some span functionality for sure.

Comment: VBA does not equal VB6. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use [VSFlexGrid](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/VSFlexGridPro/). They have products for ActiveX that incorporate nicely with VB6 and the IDE. It's not free.

The **row-span** and **column-span** can probably be accomplished with its cell-merging features.
[image: VSFlexGrid Merging]

The other configuration can be done through a GUI at design-time or through code at run-time.
[image: VSFlexGrid Design]

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Spread in my application for 10+ years.  You can do colspan and rowspan plus a whole lot more.

[Spread](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SpreadCOM/#)

Answer (score 0):

I've always used Infragistics and ComponentOne products, but I did a quick search and found SCGrid (http://scgrid.com/).  It has RowSpan and ColSpan properties and has a free version available.